# Object graph for type 'Entities.Models.ConsignmentDetails' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if references are not tracked

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Self referencing loop detected with type 'Entities.Models.ConsignmentDetails'. Path 'consignmentDetails[0].Consignee.ConsignmentDetails'.
I have possibly tried to workout with every solution on internet can't get where i am going wrong or i have messed up completley
While debugging what i get is there is an endless looped data that goes from consignees to consignmentdetails then again from consignees to consignmentdetails and it goes on
i can't change my model class as i need to get consignmentdetails when getting consignee and i also need consignee when getting consignmentdetails

#### This is my consignmentDetails Model

```
namespace Entities.Models
{
    //[ScriptIgnore]
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class ConsignmentDetails
    {
        public int ConsignmentDetailsId { get; set; }
        public int DocketNo { get; set; }
        public int? ConsignmentValue { get; set; }
        public int? Freight { get; set; }
        public int? Aoc { get; set; }
        public int? ConsigneeId { get; set; }
        .
        . 

        public virtual Consignees Consignee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### This is my Consignees Model

```
namespace Entities.Models
{
    [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Consignees
    {
        public int ConsigneeId { get; set; }
        .
        .

        public virtual ICollection<ConsignmentDetails> ConsignmentDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Inside controller I am trying to do

```
 public IActionResult GetConsigneeWithDetails(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var consignee = _repository.consignees.GetConsigneesWithDetails(id);
                if (consignee == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Consignee With Id: {id} hasn't been foud inn the db");
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInfo($"Returned Consignee with Details for id: {id}");

                    var consigneeResult = _mapper.Map<ConsigneeDTO>(consignee);
                   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(consigneeResult);


                    return Ok(consigneeResult);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"SOmething Went Wrong inside GetConsigneeWithDetails action: {ex.Message}");
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal Server Error");
            }
        }
```

#### This is how my controller is getting data

```
public Consignees GetConsigneesWithDetails(int id)
        {
            return FindByCondition(consignee => consignee.ConsigneeId.Equals(id)).Include(d => d.ConsignmentDetails).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

### the consignmentdetails model above has more than 20 properties the response i am getting is

```
{
  "consigneeId": 5,
  "consigneeName": "ABC",
  "consigneeGstno": "AFLPG-8314-H",
  "consignmentDetails": [
    {
      "$id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a package reference to **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson**.

Configure it in your Startup.cs like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options=>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        ); 

    ...
}
```

Comment: do i need to use`[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` in my model classes

Comment: [DataContract(IsReference = true)] is for XmlDCSerializer. Note that: after applying DataContract on class, you need to add DataMember to properties that you want to serialize. For more details, refer to this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223985/11965297